# Should I prune my Avocado

Tags: plant-health, indoors, avocado, winter

So, I planted without a lot of expectation an Avocado this summer.
It has now grown a lot, but yeah, except changing the water regularly and putting near the sun, I haven't done much on it, since it's just a "decoreation"

It is an indoor avocado, now around 40cm high and still in water. I was planning to move it into a pot with fertilized soil when the leaf start to get yellow/orange. (I was watching this guide some time ago : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMClGFvhm3cIt ).

But it is soon winters here, and the temperature will probably be around 3/10 degree inside (we don't sleep with the warmer).

I have seen that the best is to prune it, but since he is now kind of tall, and winter is coming, I wonder if I won't kill him by mistake, or where exactly should I prune it (if it is needed at all).

Can I keep just changing water and moving pot when it get orange as my original plan is?
Or is there some step that is better to do now that winter is coming?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would pot it immediately so it roots before the cold comes. But your question is a month old - too bad no one responded. It would be lovely if you share what you did and how did the plant like it.

Comment: I posted on Reddit and got one answer there ^^. I ended up putting it in a pot without pruning it. He is still alive and looks fine to this day. I plan to prune the top around March, cause it s starting to make new leaves on the top and it will become way to tall lol.